# How to use 'nudge_x' from 'ggrepel' within 'EnhancedVolcano'?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel, rna-seq

I'd like to fine tune the volcano plot produced using EnhancedVolcano. It's a great package with lots of customization options. I want to manually make changes to the length of Connectors, specifically, make it longer.

In this question [post](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/9150777/): Kevin (Thank you for this wonderful package!) shows how the length and other parameters are used in code chunks in *EnhancedVolcano*. In the EnhancedVolcano [vignette](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/EnhancedVolcano/inst/doc/EnhancedVolcano.html#italicise-labels-and-flip-volcano-on-its-side), it's shown that some arguments are parsed by the internal *ggrepel*.

I'd like to call `nudge_x` from *ggrepel* ([reference](https://ggrepel.slowkow.com/articles/examples.html)) within *EnhancedVolcano* function. Specifically, how can I use `nudge_x = 2` in the code below? I want to use this argument because it lengthens the connectors in *ggrepel* but I don't know how to do this in *EnhancedVolcano* function.

Here's my code:

```
EnhancedVolcano(reordered_b1,
  lab = rownames(reordered_b1),
  FCcutoff = 0.5,
  pCutoff = 0.05,
  
  selectLab = c('Gene1', 'Gene2', 'Gene3', 'Gene4'),
  labSize = 4,
  labCol = 'black',
  labFace = 'bold',
  boxedLabels = F,
  drawConnectors = T,
  widthConnectors = 1,
  lengthConnectors = unit(0, 'npc'),

  shapeCustom = keyvals.shape,
  colCustom = keyvals.color,
  
  colAlpha = .75,
  pointSize = 5,

  title = vpTitle,
  titleLabSize = 10,
  subtitle = NULL,
  legendPosition = 'none',
  caption = NULL,
  ylab = bquote(~-Log[10]~FDR),
  xlab = bquote(~Log[2]~Fold~Change),
  axisLabSize = 10,
  
  xlim = c(-6,6),
  gridlines.major = FALSE,
  gridlines.minor = FALSE,
  border = 'full')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can view the body (source) of `EnhancedVolcano` or any other function by typing the function name without parentheses and hitting Enter.

The source shows that, while `geom_text_repel` and `geom_text_label` of {ggrepel} are used, `EnhancedVolcano` unfortunately does not accept additional arguments (like, e.g. `nudge_x`) to pass through to the underlying `ggrepel` functions (you can also tell from the lack of the special [dot-dot-dot](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#fun-dot-dot-dot) argument in the function's description; see `?EnhancedVolcano`).

Comment: So, there's no way of lengthening the connector manually in EnhancedVolcano? Do you have suggestions for any other versatile volcano plot package in R? Thanks

Comment: You can set `max.overlaps = Inf` to force the display of all labels though overlapping. You can always roll your own copy `EnhancedVolcano2 <- EnhancedVolcano` and tinker with the source code. Don't know alternatives since it's the first time I came across a VP anyway.